# how do I create custom error page in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to show custom error page in my Laravel 5 app; for example any user type URL like `http://www.example.com/url123` (wrong) but `http://www.example.com/url` (right).

Default error show as :

> Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500

But instead I want to show my custom view

How I can achieve that as illustrated in the pages referenced below:

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-custom-error-pages#how-to

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page

My current `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use symfony\http-kernel\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    protected $dontReport = [
        'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
        }
        else if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            return response()->view('missing', [], 404);
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }

}
```

And I've create a error view at `\resources\views\errors\404.blade.php` but `404.blade.php` still does not get loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks guys,
Now it is working successfully,

I just change my  **app/Exceptions/Handler.php :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    protected $dontReport = [
        'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }

}
```

and create a error view on : \resources\views\errors\404.blade.php

Comment: To complete your answer, if you don't want the default error page (Whoops...) instead of returning `parent::render` you can return a response object `response()->view('my.custom.view', [], 500); `

Comment: how to get a message like page expired for 419 (not specific error)??. $exception->getMessage() give the specific error

Answer (score 10):

Im using **Laravel 6.4** and for that, You can create custom error pages blade files and Laravel will do the rest for you. Run the following command in your project directory

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

This will create blade files in `resources/views/errors/.` eg for the 404 ERROR you will have it in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php.`.
Now Let's say you wish to pass a **Not Found Error** in your sample code lets say a function to return a post category

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $count = Post::find($id)->count();

    if ($count < 1)  return abort('404', 'The post you are looking for was not found');
}
```

The `abort()` method will trigger a not found exception loading the blade file `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` and passing in the second parameter as the message. You can access this message in the blade file as

```
<h2>{{ $exception->getMessage() }}</h2>
```

Go to this link(official documentation) for details https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Answer (score 1):

first you need to type command
**php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors**

It will create some error blade files in resources/views/errors such as 404,500,403,401,419,429,503. You can customize these pages as per your design requirement.

**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    $response = parent::render($request, $exception);
    if ($response->status() === 500) {
        return response(view('errors.500'), 500);
    }
    return $response; 
}
```

**app/config/app.php**

**'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false)**

Note: Do not create errors folder manually in view folder because some library files  not creating in vendor folders. Its the reason to throw the error. please only do with the laravel command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Laravel 5.5:-

/config/constants.php

```
define('ERROR_MSG_403', "You are not authorized to view that page!");
define('ERROR_MSG_404', "Page not found!");
define('ERROR_MSG_UNKNOWN', "Something went wrong!");
```

/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        $response = [];

        $response['exception'] = get_class($e);
        $response['status_code'] = $e->getStatusCode();

        switch($response['status_code'])
        {
            case 403:
                $response['message'] = ERROR_MSG_403;
                break;
            case 404:
                $response['message'] = ERROR_MSG_404;
                break;
            default:
                $response['message'] = ERROR_MSG_UNKNOWN;
                break;
        }

        return response()->view('Error.error', compact('response'));
        // return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

/resources/views/Error/error.blade.php

```
<?=dd($response); //Implement your view layout here?>
```