# Customize view server error to 500 or 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

Is it possible to customize the views of the various errors such as server error 500 or 404 etc. in Laravel Forge? If so, how? Where are these files located?

Comment: i am not sure of forge but i have seen it in other frameworks, is there a directory like `resources/views/errors`?

Comment: If not then you can create one and add your errors but you would need a template layout to share a common view among the errors just in case

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, but there is no errors folder

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689629/how-do-i-create-custom-error-page-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages

This is the documentation for laravel 10 and other laravel versions but works also with laravel forge.